# onload add class animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a parallax but it is flipping slides.

I want to add animate.css class but it's only working on the first slide. On the other slide it's not working. It is working when page is loaded, but when I click on third slide the animation is already finished.

So, to make it work properly, I created a JQuery function when the slide is active, then animate CSSclass is to be added but it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      if ( $('#section2').hasClass('active') ) {
        $('#section2 .col-md-6').addClass('rotateInUpRight');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Can't tell what's happening, there's not enough html.

Comment: could you post the html ?

Comment: Hi Usman, we'll need some more detailed information besides "it's not working." Do you have a code sample or JS fiddle or something?

Comment: I am posting on jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=a6G04oCN39 d not know how to use it and to add js external

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add this class to the slide that has to be animated.
   Not to a container containing all slides.
2. You have to wait at least 1 animation-frame after adding the new slide to the DOM before adding this class to the new slide.
   (Or 1 animation-frame after you made it visible, in case of display:none)

If you don't know how to work with animation-frames you could use a timeout of 50ms, just to be sure.